# How to add blank row in grid view?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview, itemtemplate

I am new to the ASP.NET i am binding one list of data object to the grid view. I want to display blank row after each record in grid view so i have done this by as below in code behind

```
List<DatabaseDTO> lstdatabase= new List<DatabaseDTO>();
foreach(int jobNumber in JobnumberList)
{
    DatabaseDTO dataObject = new DatabaseDTO();
    dataobject = GetDatabaseData(jobNumber);//Method to retrieve data and return data object 
    lstdatabase.Add(dataObject);
    lstdatabase.Add(new DatabaseDTO());
}
 gridView.DataSource = lstdatabase;
 gridView.DataBind();
```

it's working correct i am getting the desired blank row in the grid view but i know this is not right way because i am adding object to the list so i can add the blank row in place of that i would very much like to adjust this blank row from the aspx page. I know there is another way using the `DataTable` but it is also not very good because it also adds the unnecessary records to the `DataTable`. So any other work around or way to solve this would be very great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<div>
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
    <ItemStyle ForeColor="#4A3C8C" BackColor="#E7E7FF"></ItemStyle>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table width="900px">
            <tr>
                <td width="300px">
                    <b>Name</b>
                </td>
                <td width="300px">
                    <b>Account No</b>
                </td>
                <td width="300px">
                    <b>Company</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table width="900px">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="300px">
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>
                </td>
                <td align="left" width="300px">
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccountNo")%>
                </td>
                <td align="left" width="300px">
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Company")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="300px">
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td align="left" width="300px">
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td align="left" width="300px">
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" BackColor="#4A3C8C"></HeaderStyle>
     <SeparatorTemplate><br /></SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an empty row in the Datagrid if it isn't present in the data source. You have to think that after all the grid data is just a representation of your data source, if there is a empty row, the grid will show it, if there is not, it wont.

Comment: So instead of data grid with the help of item -template can it is possible to complete the desired functionality

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure to get Output Parameter from sql server and bind to grid view if record is not there..