# In gridview, how to display data on alternating rows only

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How do I display data only on the alternating rows in my gridview. I need to leave the odd rows: 1,3,5,7, etc... blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after further research I decided to use a repeater (more control on rendering). I referred to this posting: [How to add blank row in grid view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484383/how-to-add-blank-row-in-grid-view).

My code:

```
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         <tr class="rowcontent">
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="dashline">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="dashline">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="dashline">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td class="content4"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Rank") %></td>
                            <td class="alternatingrow"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InnCode") %></td>
                            <td class="alternatingrow"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HOTEL_NAME") %></td>
                            <td class="alternatingrow"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ENROLLMENT_PERCENTAGE") %>%</td>
                            </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can chose not to show data in [`AlternatingItemTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.alternatingitemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) like this.

Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="SimpleGrid" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Gray"
    AlternatingRowStyle-Height="10px"
    RowStyle-Height="10px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Demo">
            <ItemTemplate><%# Container.DataItem  %></ItemTemplate>
            <AlternatingItemTemplate></AlternatingItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindSimpleGrid();
    }
}
private void BindSimpleGrid()
{
    var items = 
        new List<string>{ "Item 0", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"};
    SimpleGrid.DataSource = items;
    SimpleGrid.DataBind();
}
```

**Update**: If you want to add a blank row and still display all items, `asp:ListView` is the way to go.

Markup.

```
<asp:ListView ID="SimpleGrid" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Heading</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></tbody>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="height: 20px;"><td><%# Container.DataItem  %></td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #ddd; height: 20px;"><td></td></tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: naveen - I want the data in the AlternatingItemTemplate only. I tried the opposite of your example and only put the DataItems in the AlternatingItemTemplate and it gave me every other, even row, of data.

Comment: I thought you were using zero based index in numbering

Comment: Oh you want all the data present and a blank row

Comment: Yes, naveen. Sorry I was not clearer. It is the way the UI designer set it up visually.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking in the term of `Gridview rowindex` to show **alternating rows**.Use `OnRowDataBound` event of `Gridview`

```
 protected void gridview_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowIndex % 2 != 0)
                {
                    // do whatever you want with your odd rows
                }
                else
                {
                    // do whatever you want with your Even rows
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's not what they are asking, they are asking to fill data only into even numbered rows. Making odd rows invisible is not what the OP requested

Comment: He asked How "do I display data only on the alternating rows" .

Comment: They also said:  I need to leave the odd rows: 1,3,5,7, etc... blank.

That clarifies what they were saying, the rows are still visible but have no data inside of them

Comment: I guess maybe i misunderstood the question,i will update the ans

Comment: Right Draken, I do want the blank rows to display. This is for the design I was given for the gridview.

Comment: @TCannon do you want to display only blank row? no data inside?

Comment: Yes, blank row.  It is for the UI design. The alternating rows have a shaded color and the other rows do not. How do I post screen shot?